# Unable to locate Spring framework's 4.0.6 jar files?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm completely new in Spring and followed this tutorial http://tutorialspoint.com/spring
and this video too http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZwMwfGNrRtE

And according to this i downloaded `spring-framework-4.0.6.RELEASE-dist.zip` from [here](http://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/spring/)

I did extracted those zip files,

Now **i'm unable to locate `jars files`** into folder, But www.tutorialspoint.com/spring says It contains this [pic](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/images/spring_directories.jpg).

But into my folder(which i downloaded spring framework), I can't locate these library please help!!

I did search all jar files in that folder but i could find only [this pic](http://postimg.org/image/6a5e53ls9/)

and not being able to find these jar files:

> ```
> antlr-runtime-3.0.1
>
> org.springframework.aop-3.1.0.M2
>
> org.springframework.asm-3.1.0.M2
>
> org.springframework.aspects-3.1.0.M2
>
> org.springframework.beans-3.1.0.M2
>
> org.springframework.context.support-3.1.0.M2
>
> org.springframework.context-3.1.0.M2
>
> org.springframework.core-3.1.0.M2
>
> org.springframework.expression-3.1.0.M2
>
> commons-logging-1.1.1
> ```

Comment: Please clean this picture : `http://postimg.org/image/6a5e53ls9/` .

Comment: These are the search items that all jar files contain at the current version of Spring framework..

Comment: Maybe, but you should at least remove of mask the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well surprisingly, the dist for release 4.0.6 does not contain the jars for 3.1.0.M2 ! More seriously, under lib dir on related zip file, you will find all the jars for spring 4.0.6.

But you must have a minimal knowledge on your build environment be it maven, eclipse, Netbeans + ant, Netbeans + maven, ...

And do not forget the documentation for spring that explains what external jars are required for some operations. Notably `commons-logging-1.1.1` even if the manual explains how to use other loggin utilities.

Comment: Yes, I didn't find any `org.springframework-----.jar` files, so you mean i need to understand first Maven?

Comment: Yes, I did the unzip, Are you using `Spring-...4.0.6-RELEASE` and yes i can't find any "lib" or "docs" folder.. check this pic what it contains into folder, [see this pic pls..](http://postimg.org/image/nreczfqzt/)

Comment: Did you really unzip this [file](http://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/spring/4.0.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-4.0.6.RELEASE-dist.zip) ? It contains 3 directories : docs with the javadocs and reference manual, lib with jars and source (packaged as jars), and schema whith all needed xml schema file. But jar are now `spring-...-4.0.6-RELEASE.jar`. Maven is a tool that manages take cares of dependant jars for you : it is useful but not as much necessary than a correct IDE as Eclipse or Netbeans (Intelli-J is even better but not free).

Comment: Yes, It contains.. i've picked up something wrong file.. :p ..thanks

Comment: For future reference for ppl who have this exact same question and problem, here is the link for v4.1.4:  http://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/spring/4.1.4.RELEASE/

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using Maven, as opposed to manually downloading jar files and referring to them explicitly.

With Maven, you'd declare a dependency on the spring framework (including specific version) and you'd have all of the dependencies downloaded to a local repository, including transitory dependencies (you'd only need to specify the framework itself, for example, although in your case you'd probably need to include security and/or mvc.)

Comment: So, you mean i first need to learn `Maven` before jumping `Spring framework`?

Comment: @narayanpaliwal if you develop in java, you definetly MUST learn maven. It will save you a lot of time.